# Blank screen when connect to Xubuntu 14.04 via XRDP

Tags: linux, ubuntu, remote-desktop, vnc

When I am connecting to my XRDP (xubuntu 14.04) I see the login screen, I am entering username and password and it trying to connect. Then I see following screen:
[image]
and the session closes automatically.

I checked `/var/log/xrdp-sesman.log` log file and I see following entries there:

```
[20151019-09:50:45] [INFO ] ++ created session (access granted): username myuser, ip xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:15431 - socket: 7
[20151019-09:50:45] [INFO ] starting Xvnc session...
[20151019-09:50:46] [INFO ] starting xrdp-sessvc - xpid=6837 - wmpid=6836
[20151019-09:50:49] [INFO ] ++ terminated session:  username myuser, display :10.0, session_pid 6835, ip xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:15431 - socket: 7
(END)
```

What could be the reason? I've tried to reinstall xrdp and vnc4server, result is the same.

Answer (score 1):

may be my answer was too late you. Anyway, gnome desktop manager seems no more supported for xrdp. you have to use alternative desktop manager like xfce4.